# Generic O(1) list/array in F#?

Tags: arraylist, f#

Are arrays in F# generic or not?

[Reference section states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/arrays) that not, since it says, arrays are Systam.Array.

Simultaneously I see there is array<'T> class, which is not referred in the reference. Why and which array to use?

Comment: There's just one type of array. And yes, it's generic. And yes, it inherits from `System.Array`. Have you tried to do something with an array and failed? It's not clear what your question actually is.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin this contradicts with reference documentation, see my link

Comment: No it doesn't. Read your link carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, F# arrays are generic - here is an example of a generic function taking `array<'T>`:

```
let nth n (arr:array<'T>) = arr.[n]

nth 1 [| 1; 2; 3 |]
nth 1 [| "a"; "b" |]
```

This creates standard .NET array, so the lookup is O(1), if that was part of your question. Arrays in .NET existed before proper generics, so they are somewhat a special case (for example, reflection does not treat them as normal generic types), but from the perspective of the F# type system, they are just normal generic types.